# making a menu-driven interface that can read a list of files and delete them

Tags: shell, unix

I'm working on a shell script which is a menu-driven interface.
one of the options asks user to enter a list of optional files or directories and then the code will delete them after checking if they are valid files and directories.
the goal of the code is understanding of menu-driven interface.

my problem is reading the list of files and directory names.
It seems that sh does not support array. what is the solution for this problem?

```
2) echo "enter the name of files want to be deleted: "
read files
.
.
;;
```

Comment: If you are going to delete them anyway, why do you need to check if the names are valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
2) echo "enter the name of files want to be deleted"
    read a

for CHARACTER in $a ; do
if [ -f $CHARACTER -o -d $CHARACTER ] ; then
      rm -ir $CHARACTER
else
echo "$CHARACTER is not a valid file or directory"
fi
done
     ;;
```